# how to change color a text in HTML table through shell script

Tags: shell, scripting

Can anyone please help me with this. I have a CSV file which contains like below text. I could create an HTML file from the CSV file however unable to change the text color like for success it should be green and for all failures, it should be red.

CSV file contents

---

```
HB load,14-Jun-2018, success 
MF load,14-Jun-2018,failure
SP load,14-Jun-2018,success
LN load,14-Jun-2018,failure
```

Script

---

```
awk 'BEGIN{
FS=","
print  "<HTML>""<TABLE border="1"><TH>JOB_NAME</TH><TH>RUN_DATE</TH><TH>STATUS</TH>"
}
 {
printf "<TR>"
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
printf "<TD>%s</TD>", $i
print "</TR>"
 }
END{
print "</TABLE></BODY></HTML>"
 }
' test > file.html
(
echo "To: xyz@abc.com"
echo "Subject: Report"
echo "Content-Type: text/html"
echo
cat file.html
echo
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

file.html contents

---

```
<HTML><TABLE border=1><TH>JOB_NAME</TH><TH>RUN_DATE</TH><TH>STATUS</TH>
<TR><TD>HB load</TD><TD>14-Jun-2018</TD><TD>success </TD></TR>
<TR><TD>MF load</TD><TD>14-Jun-2018</TD><TD>failure</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>SP load</TD><TD>14-Jun-2018</TD><TD>success</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>LN load</TD><TD>14-Jun-2018</TD><TD>failure</TD></TR>
</TABLE></BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
awk 'BEGIN{
FS=","
print  "<HTML>""<TABLE border="1"><TH>JOB_NAME</TH><TH>RUN_DATE</TH><TH>STATUS</TH>"
}
 {
printf "<TR>"
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
printf "<TD>%s</TD>", $i
print "</TR>"
 }
END{
print "</TABLE></BODY></HTML>"
 }
' test > file.html
sed -i "s/failure/<font color="red">failure<\/font>/g;s/success/<font color="green">success<\/font>/g" file.html
(
echo "To: xyz@abc.com"
echo "Subject: Report"
echo "Content-Type: text/html"
echo
cat file.html
echo
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

Comment: Thanks SivaPrasath for all your help. It's working fine for me. :)